# class view in eclipse

Tags: eclipse

In Eclipse, is there a way to have a Package Explorer like view that shows the classes without having to open the files individually.

I have this project where many classes are written in same files, and that makes navigating them so annoying. Is there some sort of ClassView in Eclipse that disregards file names.

Regards

Comment: I used to use one too but can't remember the name of it.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This question is currently almost 2 years old, but for anyone ending up here through a Google search (like me):

Eclipse offers a "Java Browsing" perspective which is probably what you want. To see this, go to Window -> Open Perspective, and select Java Browsing.

Comment: that's the closest I got to the answer.. it's basically the Types view (that one can open in any perspective). The only catch is that one needs to select a package for this view to be populated

Answer (score 3):

You can use the **Outline** view. 
Window > Show View > Other. Filter by the word 'Outline' (it's under General folder)

Comment: the outline shows the classes contained in a file, only when you select the file... thanks though, but I'm looking for a Class Explorer View like thing.

Comment: Exactly what I looked for and G**gle listed as first result.

Answer (score 1):

`window->show view->outline` was helpful for me as this was the only window missing in existing perspective.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use F3 key if you're seeing this class, o you can use Ctrl+Shift+T shortcut to open 'Open Type' and write in it the name class

Comment: I may have not explained my question correctly, but I'm not looking to open a class, I'm looking to see the classes on a view similar to "Package Explorer" view, without caring in which file they are. IE I don't want to see the filenames, and I'd like to see the classes without having to drill down into each file to see what classes are inside

Answer (score 0):

Okay, it's been asked a long time ago. You may be looking for the Breadcrumb. Searching for it and got this question. Suddenly I did it unknowingly and shared here. There is a button beside "Save", "Print" buttons; "Toggle Breadcrumb". :)